# How do I count merged cells where the first one is filled?

Tags: excel, scheduler

I am making a scheduler in excel where I have conditional formatting to color-code a cell with a name, then I will manually go in and merge cells together.

1. Is there a way to enter the name and merge cells at the same time?
2. each cell represents a 1/2 hour block. How do I count up all the merged cells and separate the count based on a name so that I can get a total hour worked count for each person?

[graph image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SMKoQ.png)

Comment: Merging cells is a very bad idea and only leads to problems with formulas for counting, with cell selection and lots of other stuff. Avoid merged cells. Use Center Across Selection formatting instead.

Answer (score 0):

You may use the worksheet's Change event to take some action when a name is entered.

The data contained in a merged range of cells can be added, modified or retrieved from the `MergeArea`'s first cell.

`Cells(1, 1).MergeArea.Cells.Count` will return the number of cells merged with Cells(1, 1) (A1). You can use this count as a multiplier to calculate the marked time.